# onDestroy services crashing and restarting phone

Tags: android, restart, ondestroy

I've implemented a player service, I close app when music played and then app crashing and the phone restarting  when call onDestroy services.
how can I resolve this problem ?

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        if (!PlayerServices.mp.isPlaying()) {
            stopService(playerService);
            cancelNotification();
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: whats logs do you get. First off the static method to see if the player is playing a song is **wrong**

Comment: in avd does not display anything error bcoz this app read external storage so I installed this app in my phone

Comment: so? What does LogCat say?

Answer (score 1):

Change the sequence of your code as：

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!PlayerServices.mp.isPlaying()) {
        stopService(playerService);
        cancelNotification();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Call super.onDestroy() at last.

Comment: I has try put super.onDestroy() at last, but app still crash and restart

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on without more information. Maybe you can show your log from the logcat.

Comment: yes of course, but this app read storage.. I don't know to read from drive. OK. I'll try and find the problem. thank you all :)

Answer (score -2):

You should never call super.onDestroy() for anything. In this particular case, you're destroying the Service and then trying to stop it, which makes no sense. You should look at your logCat output as well, to satisfy yourself that this is true.

In general, if a lifecycle method expects you to call through to the method of the base class you're subclassing, the javadoc will say so. For example, take a look at Activity.onPause().

Comment: Never call `super.onDestroy()` is very wrong advice, care to edit it to explain what you actually mean?

Comment: I don't know to others way to destroy apps in home screen when music played

Comment: super.onDestroy() isn't required, and may call strange results. If you're responding to a system callback in onDestroy(), finish up your work. That's all you need to do. The system destroys your component for you.

Comment: I'm not sure who you mean by destroy apps in home screen when music played. If the user stopped your music, and you want to stop the service, call stopService(). The Service will stop, and the system will reclaim its resource. You only need to call onDestroy() if you want to handle the case where the *system* is about to destroy your Service for some reason.

Comment: @JoeMalin : I suggest you follow your own advice and look at the docs for `onDestroy()` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Comment: Joe reffers to services only. I'm also finding strange why not to call super.onDestroy. always called it.

Comment: While `Service` itself does nothing in its current implementation of `onDestroy()`, various framework-supplied subclasses of `Service` *do* actual work in `onDestroy()`. See `IntentService`, `DreamService`, and `InputMethodService` as examples. Calling through to the superclass `onDestroy()`, therefore, should be the standard recommendation, simply so developers do not have to remember which service implementations need it and which do not.